# How is text segment made read-only?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I know that text segment is a read-only segment and trying to write to it results in "Bus error".
I am curious about how this segment is made read-only.

Since the physical memory is not readonly, this must be done during paging.

Is there a bit for each page of memory for read-only pages which is set for text segment?

Comment: Depends on the architecture.  Where did you see a bus error?

Comment: There are permission flags in the page table entries.

Comment: The runtime loader is responsible for setting up the address mappings including different protection for each loaded segment. The OS is responsible for enforcing the protections at the page level. A very summarised view.

Comment: The memory protection system is aware of which pages a process can read, and to which pages a process can write. The kernel is notified when a violation occurs (which could cause it to swap in a page, for example, or send a SIGSEGV signal). Read up on memory virtualization / virtual memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, one way this happens is the program loader allocates memory for the program text, reads program text into it from the executable file, and asks the operating system to make that memory read-only. The operating system records this in its databases and conveys the information to the hardware to tell it not to allow writes to that memory.

Another possibility is that the loader does not actually read the program text into memory but merely issues a request to the operating system to mark that the appropriate portion of the executable file is “mapped” into memory, as read-only. When the process actually tries to execute the code in a memory page, the operating system will read it into memory (with write access for itself, so it can do this) and mark it read-only (for the process).

This latter case is an optimization because it allows your program to start without loading all of it first. And parts of it that are never used, such as code to handle rare errors, might never be loaded.

Comment: @Sandy: Different hardware has different ways of handling that. Commonly there are page table entries of various formats that tell the hardware that some virtual memory address is mapped to some physical memory address with some permissions, and sometimes with information about for which processes. Page table entries may be conveyed to the hardware by putting them in special memory locations or special registers or by using special instructions, depending on the hardware.

Answer (score 6):

An ELF file (a Unix executable or a shared-object) has two main concepts:

**Section:** An area inside the executable file with a specific role. There may be different sections inside an ELF file (can be seen in [man elf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/elf)). Common sections in an ELF file are:

- `.text` (SHT_PROGBITS): The actual executable code in the ELF file.
- `.dynsym` (SHT_DYNSYM): Holds information about symbols that should be dynamically retrieved.
- `.rela.dyn` and `.rela.plt` (SHT_RELA): Hold relocation information for the dynamic linker to use when loading the ELF file into memory.
- `.dynamic` (SHT_DYNAMIC): Holds information for the dynamic linker, such as other dependencies, offsets for different sections in run-time, etc.
- `.symtab` (SHT_SYMTAB): Holds a symbol table.
- `.strtab` (SHT_STRTAB): Holds a string table.

There are more sections and the above are just a few common ones.

Using `readelf` one can see all the sections in an ELF file:

```
readelf --sections -W <file>
```

Running this command on a shared-object in my computer results in the following output (simplified):

```
There are 29 section headers, starting at offset 0x1898:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
...
  [ 3] .dynsym           DYNSYM          0000000000000230 000230 000168 18   A  4   2  8
  [ 4] .dynstr           STRTAB          0000000000000398 000398 0000b0 00   A  0   0  1
...
  [ 7] .rela.dyn         RELA            0000000000000488 000488 0000c0 18   A  3   0  8
  [ 8] .rela.plt         RELA            0000000000000548 000548 000030 18  AI  3  22  8
...
  [12] .text             PROGBITS        00000000000005e0 0005e0 000121 00  AX  0   0 16
...
  [20] .dynamic          DYNAMIC         0000000000200e18 000e18 0001c0 10  WA  4   0  8
...
  [23] .data             PROGBITS        0000000000201028 001028 000008 00  WA  0   0  8
...
  [27] .symtab           SYMTAB          0000000000000000 001068 000570 18     28  45  8
  [28] .strtab           STRTAB          0000000000000000 0015d8 0001c6 00      0   0  1
```

**Segment:** An area inside the executable with load instructions for the dynamic linker. Meaning, a segment is just an area inside the ELF file that should be loaded into a preferred address memory, and have specific permissions, alignment, etc.

Every section (which is an area in the ELF file with a logical role) should be part of a segment, with the correct permissions and characteristics. A segment can have more than a single section within, and a section is inside a single segment (one-to-many relation).

Using `readelf` one can see all segments in an ELF file:

```
readelf --segments -W <file>
```

Running this command on a shared-object in my computer results in the following output:

```
There are 7 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x00079c 0x00079c R E 0x200000
  LOAD           0x000e00 0x0000000000200e00 0x0000000000200e00 0x000230 0x000238 RW  0x200000
  DYNAMIC        0x000e18 0x0000000000200e18 0x0000000000200e18 0x0001c0 0x0001c0 RW  0x8
  NOTE           0x0001c8 0x00000000000001c8 0x00000000000001c8 0x000024 0x000024 R   0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x000718 0x0000000000000718 0x0000000000000718 0x00001c 0x00001c R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x000e00 0x0000000000200e00 0x0000000000200e00 0x000200 0x000200 R   0x1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .plt.got .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame 
   01     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   02     .dynamic 
   03     .note.gnu.build-id 
   04     .eh_frame_hdr 
   05     
   06     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got
```

Here, we can see that all sections related to the executable code, as well as many sections related to the dynamic loading of the file are in segment 00 (PT_LOAD), which has read and executable permissions (`R E`). Sections that should be modified by the loader are in segment 01 (PT_LOAD) which has read and write permissions (`RW`). Segment 02 is of type PT_DYNAMIC and holds dynamic linking information - the `.dynamic` section.

The dynamic linker takes all this information into account when it loads the ELF file into memory. It loads the different segments of the ELF file from disk into memory and protects their pages with the correct permissions. Then, it iterates through the different sections and uses them according to their roles (relocations, resolving dynamic symbols, etc...).

The memory protection itself is being made by the OS and the hardware itself. It is similar to using the Linux methods [mprotect()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html). More information about memory protection can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection).

Comment: I have an object file with 25 sections, but zero segments. How is this possible?

Comment: Can you share the output of `readelf --segments <YOUR ELF FILE>`?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be.  You can make the text segment of a program read write.  But you have to instruct the linker about that.  The operating system generates pages that generate a page fault when you try to write on them, but not when you try to read.  This is part of the multiuser protection system (also called the memory protection system).

The reason of the text segment being read only is a legacy from ancient time.  The multiple instances of a single program called by different processes (e.g. different users doing a `ls` to show their own directory contents) use the same segment as text, so *why not share that segment and avoid to load it each time for each instance?*  That's the reason, but if you want to modify your program's text segment at runtime, you can designate it to be COW ((C)opy (o)n (w)rite) and the pages will be individually copied when you try to write on them, so you have the illussion it is read/write.